# Sinatra::Streaming with Rack not chunking response

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I'm having a rough time trying to get this simple streaming test to work using Sinatra and Rack.

In my *stream.rb* file, I have:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/streaming'
class StreamAPI < Sinatra::Base
    helpers Sinatra::Streaming
    get '/stream' do
        stream do |out|
            5.times do
                out.puts "Hello!"
                sleep 1
            end
            out.flush
        end
    end
    run! if app_file == $0
end
```

And in my *config.ru* I have:

```
require 'rack'
require './stream.rb'
run StreamAPI
```

When I curl the url, I get "Hello!" 5 times, but all at once after 5 seconds.  Looking at the headers I can see that `Transfer-Encoding` is set to `Chunked`.  What I want is for the a "Hello!" to come through then another after a 1 second pause.

---

**Edit:** Along with the selected answer below, I also needed to add `proxy_buffering off;` to my NGINX configuration file.

Comment: Not that familiar with streaming but your code is asking it to `puts "Hello!"` every second not every 5 seconds.

Comment: Oops sorry, I was trying a bunch of different values and put the wrong one here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on which server you are using. From the [Sinatra README](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Streaming%20Responses):

> Note that the streaming behavior, especially the number of concurrent requests, highly depends on the web server used to serve the application. Some servers, like WEBRick, might not even support streaming at all. If the server does not support streaming, the body will be sent all at once after the block passed to stream finishes executing.

It looks like you are using a server that doesn’t support streaming. If you switch to one that does (e.g. [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) or [Puma](http://puma.io/)) this should work.

Comment: So if I install thin, then use `set :server, 'thin'` it should use thin and not webrick and this should solve my issue?

Comment: @ecnepsnai yes, that should work. In fact you probably don’t need to add `set :server, :thin` as it will be detected automatically, but it would be safer to include if you are relying on it.

Comment: @ecnepsnai If you’re using `rackup` then `set :server, :thin` won’t work (it only affects the Sinatra built-in server), in that case you would need to use `rackup -s thin` (although `rackup` will likely detect Thin automatically if it installed). You could also add `#\ -s thin` to your `config.ru` which would have the same effect.

Comment: So I'm using thin now, but it's still not working as I expected it to.  I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: Except now responses take exactly 1 minute to come in even with no `sleep` commands.

Comment: Ignore my last two comments - the problem was with NGINX - I needed to use the `proxy_buffering off;` statement.